# Why is a char with a value of 128 an empty string and not a Euro sign €

Tags: c#, char, ascii

Following the ASCII table here [asci table](http://www.ascii-code.com/) the value for 128 is a
`€` However doing the follwoing code in C# doesn't return the euro sign

```
char expectedEuro = Convert.ToChar(128);
```

Trying to convert the `€` character into a Char always results in an `OverflowException` as it is too big for an unsigned byte

```
Convert.ToByte(`€`);
```

This is causing problems as our encoding from another system outputs the  `€` character when there is a value of 128 but C# outputs an empty character.

Is there an explanation for this and anything I can do to work around this?

Comment: `Convert.ToChar(128) // returns €` `Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToChar(128)) // returns 128` I don't understand your issue?

Comment: Be thankful that C# and .NET and the IT industry in general has switched to Unicode. (Did it many years ago, in fact.) I'm old enough to remember all the never-ending crazy crazy problems of incompatible character sets and ASCII vs. EBCDIC vs. code pages, etc. etc. from back in the 1970's and 1980's.

Comment: An ASCII library or system is rare. When you find yourself thinking "ASCII," stop and determine what the actual character set and encoding are. For a .NET library, it's almost always Unicode/UTF-16 (in machine byte order) or Unicode/UTF-8 for file streams. So, you'll have to determine what character set/encoding your other system uses and then use an `Encoding` class to convert properly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C#/.NET uses Unicode characters, so the `€` sign is `8364`.

You can check that with:

```
int val = (int)'€'; // val will be 8364
```

This also means you can not represent a `char` as one `byte` as most of them need 2 bytes.

If you want to use the extended ASCII table you can use `Encoding.Default`:

```
var valStr = Encoding.Default.GetString(new byte[] { 128 }); // valStr = €
var valByte = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("€"); // valByte[0] = 128
```

[`Encoding.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx) uses the current ANSI code page (*see Joe's answer or Jeppe's comment to choose a specific one*) and [`Encoding.ASCII`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx) uses the 7-bit ASCII table, so there is no `128` in `ASCII`.

Comment: This is the correct explanation. Under Unicode, decimal 128, or U+0080, is "PAD – Padding Character" C1 control character, see [Latin-1 Supplement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block)). **ADDITION:** See the Euro sign in [Currency Symbols block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_Symbols_(Unicode_block)).

Comment: Additionally, the page the asker links to really gives the [Windows 1252 codepage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) which is *not* Unicode. One should not use the Windows-1252 specific codepoints with .NET.

Comment: Encoding.Default is not necessarily CP1252, so to work internationally you should instead explicitly specify the encoding you want.

Comment: Warning: The trick with `Encoding.Default` will give the codepage native to the operating system. It will be Windows-1252 for "Western European language" versions of Windows, but if the code runs on a Bulgarian or Greek language version of Windows, it would give another codepage. Therefore it is more safe to use `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")`.

Comment: @Joe: Thanks, just added it to the answer.

Comment: @Joe Ah, you wrote it first. Will leave my comment, though, since it gives the specific synatx to use.

Answer (score 4):

ASCII is a 7-bit encoding: the table you linked describes one specific encoding for the Euro character.

If you want to encode the Euro symbol so that it's recognized by the other system, you may want to encode it using a suitable encoding, e.g.:

```
var v = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes("€");
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToByte(v[0])); // = 128
```